# React Native Metro bundler choose file to import. How to make behaviour was as Webpack resolver mainFiles

Tags: reactjs, react-native, metro-bundler

In React-Native we can import files depends on a platform. 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code#platform-specific-extensions

```
button.ios.js
button.android.js

import button from './button';
```

Platform specified button will be imported.

SO!

How can i expand this behavior as WebPack allows with mainFiles resolver

EXAMPLE:

```
button.uk.js
button.br.js
button.us.js

/*
set build variable env.country = uk
*/

import button from './button';
uk button imported
```

Looks like that Metro bundler already had those options, but i dont understand how to pass an option via react-native-cli.
Should i try to run bundler by myself without cli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haul bundler for react native allows to do that pretty simple
https://callstack.github.io/haul/
It replaces metro bundler and allows you pass a webpack config with plugins etc...

Use Github documentation instead of web, their web doc is pretty old.
But the bundler works fine.